# Command-clicking a link in Google Chrome loads page without rendering it (regular click works)

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, rendering, source-code

I am building a site at [svija.love](https://svija.love).

We are getting complaints that when someone clicks on a link to the site from Facebook, in Chrome, they just get a blank page.

I have reproduced the behavior: if I click on a link in WhatsApp web, it opens in a new tab.

If I command-click the a link to the site, the page *seems* to load (correct favicon, loading bar etc.) but it's just a **white page**.

If I use the **Web Inspector**, the page instantly displays correctly.

If I **reload** the page, it loads correctly.

It's as though the browser is **waiting for something** before drawing the page, and the something never comes.

Also, if I just click the link (not command-click), the page loads correctly.

Anybody have any ideas about what might be happening?

Comment: MacOS, all updates

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvoted explained why… I could make the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trebor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/132614/64375)'s answer on **webmasters.stackexchange.com** helped me come up with a test that clarified the issue.

The following code can be visited at [files.svija.love/chrome/test.html](http://files.svija.love/chrome/test.html):

```
<html><head><script>

  t = 0;

  function updateTitle(){
     t += 10;
     document.title=t + ': ' + window.outerWidth;
     }

   x = window.setInterval(updateTitle, 10);

</script></head><body></body></html>
```

The script sets the page title to equal window.outerWidth.

You can command-click the link, then watch the value of outerWidth change in the adjacent tab title.

**In Chrome, it is set to zero until the window is focused.**

Interestingly, the setinterval function runs at approximately 1/10th speed until the window is focused, also.

*This answer was also posted on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132556/chrome-bug-headless-window-not-rendered-new-tab-in-background-if-outerwidth-i).*